# Timing how long it takes

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm making a simple code about divisors and I'd like to have a feedback on how long it takes for the computer to give me an answer.

Here's my code:

```
num=int(input('Give me a number'))
listRange=list(range(1,num+1))
divisorList=[]
for number in listRange:
    if num%number==0:
        divisorList.append(number)
print(divisorList)
```

As you can see, the bigger the number, more time the computer takes to process all the divisors, so I wanna know how much time it spends whilst doing that.

Comment: *O(n)* with *n* the value entered. But you can do this better: in *O(sqrt n)*.

Comment: Look at [timeit.py](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) or the time module.

Comment: You could do a prime factorization of the number then generate all combinations of factors.

Comment: @KindStranger It's far fewer than half; it's sqrt(n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the time module to a timestamp before the loop and another after and print the difference.

```
import time

num=int(input('Give me a number'))
listRange=list(range(1,num+1))
divisorList=[]
start = time.time() # use time.clock() if on Windows
for number in listRange:
        if num%number==0:
            divisorList.append(number)
end = time.time() # use time.clock() if on Windows
print(divisorList)
print("Time taken: {:06.5f}secs".format(end-start)) # Seconds
print("Time taken: {:10.5f}ms".format((end-start)*1000) # Miliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the time in seconds:

```
from time import time
start = time()
... # code
print(time() - start)
```

Comment: And what if i'm looking for the time in miliseconds(ms)?

Comment: @LFSS `time.time()` returns a `float` so simply multiply the answer by 1000

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `timeit` module:

```
import timeit

num=100000
listRange=list(range(1,num+1))

def function():
    divisorList=[]
    for number in listRange:
        if num%number==0:
            divisorList.append(number)

print(timeit.timeit(function, number=1))
# 0.01269146570884061
```